# I cannot separate out the junk values in case of negative integers output, while sorting out positive, negative and zeroes from the array

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```
{
   int num[11], pos[11], neg[11], zero[11], new[11], ni=0, nu=0, ny=0;
   for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter the number: ");
      scanf("%d", &num[i]);
   }
   for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
   {
      if(num[i] > 0)
      {
         pos[i] = num[i];
         ni++;
      }
      if(num[i] < 0)
      {
         neg[i] = num[i];
         nu++;
      }
      
      if(num[i] == 0)
      {
         zero[i] = num[i];
         ny++;
      }
   }
   printf("There are %d positive numbers and they are: \n", ni);
   for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
   {
      if(pos[i] != 0)
      {
         printf("%d, ", pos[i]);
      }
   }
   printf("\n");
   printf("There are %d negative numbers and they are: \n", nu);
   for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
   {
      if(neg[i] != 0 )
      {
         printf("%d, ", neg[i]);
      }
   }
   printf("\n");

   printf("There are %d zeroes \n",ny);
   
}
```

I tried to separate out the positive, negative and the zeroes from an array after taking those as an input, but while printing the negative values together at last some junk values are getting printed every time. How to stop those junk values from getting printed in my output. The postitive and the zeroes condition are done.

Comment: You must initialize the arrays (i.e. `pos[11] = { 0 }`)

Comment: Uninitialized local variables, including arrays, really are uninitialized, and will have *indeterminate* values. You should think of them as garbage values. Your loop where you set values in `pos`, `neg`, and `zero` might not assign to all elements in those arrays, leaving some elements uninitialized and with the "garbage" indeterminate values.

Comment: You should probably also use `ni`, `nu` and `ny` as indexes when assigning to those arrays. And use the counter variables as loop limiter when you print the arrays.